# how to install carla simulator in google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, carla

I am trying to run carla simulator in a google colab with python jupyter notebook.
I followed the [guide](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start_quickstart/#installation-summary) and I executed the following commands

```
!pip install pygame
!pip install numpy
!sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 304F9BC29914A77D
!sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] http://dist.carla.org/carla-0.9.8/ all main"
!sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DB53A429E64554FC &&
!sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] http://dist.carla.org/carla-0.9.7/ all main"
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt-get install carla
```

however when I tried to run it I got an error

> Package carla is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is
>   only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'carla' has no installation candidate

how can I install the carla simulator on google colab?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this repo: https://github.com/MichaelBosello/carla-colab
There is google colab notebook with pre-installed Carla.

Comment: Tried this one but I'm unable to connect ngrok. I'm getting: "Connection refused". Does anyone was able to complete it and have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Yes, I used that notebook and it worked for me. 
Check the correctness of ngrok installation. Did you use right token from the ngrok account? Did it authorize you?

Comment: I got one step further, but now I'm stuck on ssh Permission denied error.

Comment: Check [this issue](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/145)